# How to stretch an image in a SVG shape to fill its bounds?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG shape (a parallelogram) which is filled with an image. The demo can be [**seen here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/E87AP/).

The SVG object is:

```html
<svg style="overflow:visible; margin-left:111px; margin-top:22px; " height="86" width="281">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="blip1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="279" height="83">
            <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/uTDpE6J.jpg" width="279" height="83"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="49,2 280,2 232,84 1,84" x="1" y="1" style="stroke-linejoin:round; fill:url(#blip1); stroke-width:2; stroke:hsl(212,45%,26%); "></polygon>
</svg>
```

But the image is not stretched to the bounds of the shape, instead it lies in the middle of the shape.

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image: Desired result]

But what I am getting is this:

[image: Actual result]

Can anyone suggest me a solution that will apply to all shapes (i.e. pentagon, hexagon, star etc.)? BTW it already works fine with ellipses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `preserverAspectRatio=none` to the image object <s>and setting width/height to 100%</s> seems to do what you want. [Updated fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/E87AP/2/)

```html
<svg style="overflow:visible; margin-left:111px; margin-top:22px; " height="86" width="281">

    <defs>
        <pattern id="blip1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="279" height="83">
             <image preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/uTDpE6J.jpg" width="279" height="83"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <polygon points="49,2 280,2 232,84 1,84" x="1" y="1" style="stroke-linejoin:round; fill:url(#blip1); stroke-width:2; stroke:hsl(212,45%,26%); ">
    </polygon>

</svg>
```

Comment: thanx a lot... that worked like a charm. However setting width and height to 100% was not needed.

Comment: cool, i tried that first and hadnt removed it, will edit answer

Comment: just fyi you could accomplish a similar affect with css shapes.

Comment: If you want the image enlarged to fill the shape, rather than stretched, then use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` instead.