# Stretch image to fit polygon html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a square image like this:

[image]

I am trying to stretch this image into a polygon like this:

[image]

So far I have been able to create a polygon on the canvas as the above image using the following javascript:

```
function drawCanvas() {
        var c2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas6').getContext('2d');
        var img = document.getElementById("scream");
        c2.fillStyle = '#000';
        c2.beginPath();
        c2.moveTo(20, 20);
        c2.lineTo(320, 50);
        c2.lineTo(320, 170);
        c2.lineTo(20, 200);
        //c2.drawImage(img, 150, 10, img.width, img.height);
        c2.closePath();
        c2.fill();

    }
```

I tried using `drawImage()` method, but it does not stretch the points A, B, C, D to the new positions. Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: Using a canvas, might not be the ideal control.  SVG's are great at doing this sort of stuff.

Comment: @Keith Can you point to a source where I can get a quick idea please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660085/how-to-stretch-an-image-in-a-svg-shape-to-fill-its-bounds

Answer (score 2):

The 2D canvas is called 2D for a very good reason. You can not transform a square such that any of its side converge (are not parallel) hence 2D

But where there is a need there is always a way..

You can do it by cutting the image into slices and then draw each slice slightly smaller than the last.

We humans don't like to see an image distort when it converges, so you need to add the distortion we expect, perspective. The further away the object the smaller the distance between points appears to the eye.

So the function below draws an image with the top and bottom edges converging..

It is not true 3D but it does make the image appear as distorted as jus converging the top and bottom without decreasing the y step. The animation introduced a bit of an optical illusion. the second render shortens the image to make it appear a little less fake.

See the code on how to use the function.

```js
/** CreateImage.js begin **/
// creates a blank image with 2d context
var createImage=function(w,h){var i=document.createElement("canvas");i.width=w;i.height=h;i.ctx=i.getContext("2d");return i;}

/** CreateImage.js end **/

var can = createImage(512,512);
document.body.appendChild(can);
var ctx = can.ctx;
const textToDisplay = "Perspective"
const textSize = 80;
ctx.font = textSize+"px arial";
var w = ctx.measureText(textToDisplay).width + 8;
var text = createImage(w + 64,textSize + 32);
text.ctx.fillStyle = "#08F";
text.ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
text.ctx.lineWidth = 16;
text.ctx.fillRect(0,0,text.width,text.height);
text.ctx.strokeRect(0,0,text.width,text.height);
text.ctx.font = textSize+"px arial";
text.ctx.fillStyle = "#F80";
text.ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
text.ctx.lineWidth = 4;
text.ctx.strokeText(textToDisplay,38,textSize + 8);
text.ctx.fillText(textToDisplay,38,textSize + 8);






// Not quite 3D
// ctx is the context to draw to
// image is the image to draw
// x1,x2 left and right edges of the image
// zz1,zz2 top offset for left and right
// image top edge has a slops from zz1 to zz2
// yy if the position to draw top. This is where the top would be if z = 0
function drawPerspective(ctx, image, x1, zz1, x2, zz2, yy){
    var x, w, h, h2,slop, topLeft, botLeft, zDistR, zDistL, lines, ty;
    w    = image.width;                   // image size
    h    = image.height;
    h2   = h /2;                          // half height
    slop = (zz2 - zz1) / (x2 - x1);       // Slope of top edge
    z1   = h2 - zz1;                      // Distance (z) to first line
    z2   = (z1 / (h2 - zz2)) * z1 - z1;   // distance (z) between first and last line
    if(z2 === 0){ // if no differance in z then is square to camera
        topLeft = - x1 * slop + zz1;      // get scan line top left edge
        ctx.drawImage(image,0, 0, w, h,x1, topLeft + yy ,x2-x1, h - topLeft * 2)  // render to desination 
        return;
    }
    // render each display line getting all pixels that will be on that line
    for (x = x1; x < x2; x++) {                 // for each line horizontal line
        topLeft = (x - x1) * slop + zz1;        // get scan line top left edge
        botLeft = ((x + 1) - x1) * slop + zz1;  // get scan line bottom left edge
        zDistL  = (z1 / (h2 - topLeft)) * z1;   // get Z distance to Left of this line
        zDistR  = (z1 / (h2 - botLeft)) * z1;   // get Z distance to right of this line
        ty      = ((zDistL - z1) / z2) * w;     // get y bitmap coord
        lines   = ((zDistR - z1) / z2) * w - ty;// get number of lines to copy
        ctx.drawImage(image,
            ty % w, 0, lines, h,                // get the source location of pixel
            x, topLeft + yy,1 , h - topLeft * 2 // render to desination 
        );
    }
}


var animTick = 0;
var animRate = 0.01;
var pos = 0;
var short = 0;
function update1(){
    animTick += animRate;
    pos =  Math.sin(animTick) * 20 + 20;
    short =  Math.cos((pos / 40) * Math.PI) * text.width * 0.12 -  text.width * 0.12;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height)

    drawPerspective(ctx,text,0,0,text.width,pos,20)

    drawPerspective(ctx,text,0,0,text.width+short,pos,textSize + 32 + 30)


    requestAnimationFrame(update1);
}
update1();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fQk4h/
Here is the magic:

```
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
dy = (leftTop * (w - i)) / w;
dh = (leftBot * (w - i) + h * i) / w;
ctx.drawImage(tmpCtx.canvas,
    i, 0, 1, h,
    i, dy, 1, dh);
}

ctx.restore();
```

Comment: amazing, maybe I am wrong, but this code doesnt work once you change to any other image

Comment: I tried this image http://ielts-results.weebly.com/uploads/4/0/6/6/40661105/1113084_orig.jpg and it worked for me, however you have to be adapt the screen sizes in the script.